# i can't upload png thumbnail only i get uploaded JPG image

Tags: php, image, jpeg

i have problem with my uploading image wheen i upload it load only see the JPG thumbnail but the png thumbnail does't show.
how to convert images to JPG from any type like PNG,GIF all to JPG that it can show the thumbnail image. sorry for my bad english.
here my code

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
    $file_name = $key.$rd.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $filePath = "img/zoekertjes/";

    $desired_dir="img/zoekertjes";
    if(empty($errors)==true){

        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", "img/zoekertjes",true);       
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){

            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);

            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($tmp_name);


            $newwidth=($width/$height)*300;
            $newheight=300;
            $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);



            imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
            $rd=rand();

            $filename = "img/thumbphotos/".$file_name;
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

            imagedestroy($src);

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir);                
            }
              $query="INSERT INTO `t_images` (d_image_naam, d_image_images) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$file_name')";
         mysqli_query($db,$query);          
        }
        else
        {

     print_r($errors);

    }
```

Comment: You are not checking the extension, you simply use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` for all uploads. So that will fail for non-jpeg files.

Comment: @jeroen and how can i add the extension?

Comment: You check what kind of file was uploaded and process it accordingly, using `imagecreatefromjpeg()`, `imagecreatefrompng()`, etc.

Comment: so i can add just like this

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_name);
?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by jereon you want to check the file type then read the file based on the type.

This is the line that is causing issues:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
```

This will fail if the file isn't `image/jpeg`. You will need to check the mime type then read the image based off that. You will need to use something like this to read the mime type and create the `$src` image:

```
switch (mime_content_type($tmp_name)) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
        break;

    case 'image/png':
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_name);
        break;

    case 'image/gif':
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($tmp_name);
        break;

    default:
        // If mime type is unknown, you can't process it
        throw new Exception('Unknown file type');
        break;
}
```